# Failed to resolve: com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2

Tags: android-studio, gradle

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.uts.balamtour"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'

    //Rest API FAN
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.1'
}
```

build.gradle(project:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

when I import it into activity.java like below

```
import com.androidnetworking.AndroidNetworking;
import com.androidnetworking.common.Priority;
import com.androidnetworking.error.ANError;
import com.androidnetworking.interfaces.JSONArrayRequestListener;
```

there are some errors

- Cannot resolve symbol 'androidnetworking'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidNetworking'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'Priority'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'JSONObjectRequestListener'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'ANError'

Answer (score 4):

Add `jcenter()` in `settings.gradle` and sync the project with `gradle` files.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() //add jcenter
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() //add jcenter
    }
}
rootProject.name = <your app name>
include <your module name>
```